# Log IP of signed in user with ASP.net core Identity MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

### What I want to achieve:

Save the IP of a User hitting specific actions/controllers to my database. Also since this process takes a significant amount of time it would be good if it gets executed on a background thread or similar.

### What I tried so far:

Creating a CustomAuthorizeAttribute that looks something like this:

```cs
    public class LoggedAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public LoggedAuthorizeAttribute() : base(typeof(LoggedAuthorizeFilter))
        {
        }
    }

    public class LoggedAuthorizeFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

        public LoggedAuthorizeFilter(UserManager<User> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (!context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return;

            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.HttpContext.User);

            var remoteIpAddress = context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

            user.UserLogins.Add(new UserLogin
                {LoggedInOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, LoggedInFrom = remoteIpAddress});

            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        }
    }
```

**Problems with this solution:**

1. When the request hits an action marked with this attribute the request will take about 1-2 seconds until it actually processes the action.
2. The UserManager is retrieved by Dependency Injection, but I also access the UserManager instance in some of my Actions which causes a `InvalidOperationException` telling `A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This could also be caused by a nested query being evaluated on the client, if this is the case rewrite the query avoiding nested invocations.`.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

### Update

As suggested by `Kirk Larkin` implementing the IAsyncActionFilter instead fixes my second issue I ran into. But still how would I perform this in a Background Thread or similar, if this is even the right choice.

Comment: `async void` is causing your issues here. You should never need `async void` in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Yeah I know that `async void` should be avoided. How could I create an attribute with a similar result then?

Comment: In terms of a solution, you *could* implement [`IAsyncAuthorizationFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iasyncauthorizationfilter?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and use `await` correctly, but what you're doing isn't really authorisation. It might be better suited to a [Resource Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#resource-filters) or a maybe an [Action Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#action-filters).

Comment: @KirkLarkin I wanted to try it with an Action Filter but I need to implement or override a method which return a Task then which only leaves me with `IAsyncActionFilter` which would again block the execution and the request "takes forever".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed my first issue with the use of a `ConcurrentQueue` which dequeues its items on a Background Thread. I found this solution in [this](https://www.tpeczek.com/2018/03/push-notifications-and-aspnet-core-part.html) blog post. It just needs some slight modifications in order to work for this problem.